# Windows 7+ Recent Places is not sorted by date

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1

Recent Places is a great feature in Windows 7 and up, but it's frustrating to me that it's always sorted in alphabetical order on the folder name. The result is that the most recent place isn't at the top. When I access Recent Places in an application such as Word, I have to click the date column (every time) to make it re-sort the list of folders.

How can I set it so that the contents of Recent Places is always sorted by order of most recent folder first?

Answer (score 0):

Change view to details

1. Change View to Details (In case it's set to list / thumbnails / icons, etc)
2. Click on the **Date Modified** Heading to sort by date.